# Character set issue in PHP

Tags: php, character-encoding

In my project I have many strings containing characters like 'à', 'è', 'ì', 'ò' and 'ù'. My issue is well explained by this simple statements:

$a = "Casturà";
echo $a;

This is the result:

CasturÃ

My files are UTF-8 and in **my php.ini** I included **default_charset = "UTF-8"**.
Many thanks

Comment: Use `utf8_decode` to the db result , for eg : `utf8_decode($a); `

Answer (score 0):

try the following code:

```php
$str = "Casturà"; 
utf8_encode($str);
```

Comment: In my opinion this is not the right solution to the problem user has. I use Polish characters like `śąź` and I can use them in my php files without any additional combinations like `utf8_encode` - I suppose there's just a problem with PHP file encoding or font face.